# Newton's Method with Looping Recursion

Tags: python, recursion

I have the code here all figured out. The directions say to **"Convert Newton’s method for approximating square roots in Project 1 to a recursive function named newton. (Hint: The estimate of the square root should be passed as a second argument to the function.)"**
How would I work out these directions according to my code here?

```
# Initialize the tolerance
TOLERANCE = 0.000001
def newton(x):
    """Returns the square root of x."""
    # Perform the successive approximations
    estimate = 1.0
    while True:
        estimate = (estimate + x / estimate) / 2
        difference = abs(x - estimate ** 2)
        if difference <= TOLERANCE:
            break
    return estimate
def main():
    """Allows the user to obtain square roots."""
    while True:
        # Receive the input number from the user
        x = input("Enter a positive number or enter/return to quit: ")
        if x == "":
             break
        x = float(x)
        # Output the result
        print("The program's estimate is", newton(x))
        print("Python's estimate is     ", math.sqrt(x))
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: What do you already know about recursive functions?

Comment: not a ton, thats why Im so confused on it

Answer (score 2):

essentialy you need to convert the `while True:` part of your code in the recursive function
something like this:

```
def newton(x, estimate):
    estimate = (estimate + x / estimate) / 2
    difference = abs(x - estimate ** 2)
    if difference > TOLERANCE:
        estimate = newton(x, estimate)
    return estimate
```

notice how the condition is different so you check if you need to continue, after you don't the final value is carried along out of the recursion and returned

Comment: That does not seem to fix the issue. "def newton(x, estimate): seems to create conflict in the last two print lines of the code.

Comment: What issue do you have?

Comment: Yes, but what *is* the issue?

Comment: you would need to initialize this with estimate as 1 when you call it, i tried it and it working with the code you provided what's the is the issue? thanks for the edit quamrana

Comment: It says name 'estimate' not defined, is there a secondary place where i would define this?

Comment: newton now accepts 2 arguments x and estimate so yeah you need to call it by `newton(x, 1.0)`

Comment: it says invalid syntax on newton(x, 1.0)

Comment: so for the def newton(x, estimate=1.0) is the proper syntax

Answer (score 0):

This is the full code of the answer and comments discussion of **jimakr**

I utilized this in the def newton function (credits to **NP890**):

```
def newton(x, estimate = 1.0):
```

I also import **math** module to utilize the math.sqrt :

```
def main():
        """Allows the user to obtain square roots."""
        while True:
            import math
#Continuation
```

**THE FULL CODE:**

```
# Initialize the tolerance
TOLERANCE = 0.000001
def newton(x, estimate = 1.0):
    """Returns the square root of x."""
    # Perform the successive approximations
    estimate = (estimate + x / estimate) / 2
    difference = abs(x - estimate ** 2)
    if difference > TOLERANCE:
        estimate = newton(x, estimate)
    return estimate
def main():
    """Allows the user to obtain square roots."""
    while True:
        import math
        # Receive the input number from the user
        x = input("Enter a positive number or enter/return to quit: ")
        if x == "":
             break
        x = float(x)
        # Output the result
        print("The program's estimate is", newton(x))
        print("Python's estimate is     ", math.sqrt(x))
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```